# SQL Azure cross-server copy error

Tags: azure-sql-database

I've been struggling with a SQL Azure cross-server copy for a bit now - and hopefully I'm doing something silly.  Both servers are under the same subscription and in the same region.  Both servers have the same DBO user and password (the destination server is a fresh server specifically for this copy).

Following the documentation [Copying Databases in SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951624.aspx),  I get the following error when executing from the destination server:

> Msg 10054, Level 20, State 0, Line 0 A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Checking the error listing found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/4cff491e-9359-4454-bd7c-fb72c4c452ca#bkmk_copy_errors), that error number is evidently something to do with federated data.

I'm a bit stuck as what to try next - any ideas?

Comment: You get this error when you do what exactly? Are you getting the error when you execute the CREATE DATABASE statement?  Do you have anything that shows up when you execute this SQL:  select * from sys.dm_database_copies    after the CREATE DATABASE statement?  Finally, are you copying a federated database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a RedGate tool to do this.  The [SQL Azure Backup tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/) allows you to do exactly what I was attempting to do.

I never did figure out exactly what the problem was, but I hypothesize it's because I was trying to copy a database across servers under different accounts.